# How do I force Windows system directories to be on a volume other than C:?

Tags: windows-xp

What title said.

Background: a customer has done this somehow and he doesn't remember how. I must reproduce this to investigate a possible bug in the application I'm maintaining.

Comment: not sure but I think that when you install you get the options of disks. To simulate the situation, you might be able to try installing the XP on a guest in a VirtualBox.

Comment: Are you trying to install or move the whole windows directory to another drive? Or trying to move specific folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to somehow boot into a different Windows, mount the HKLM registry hive, go to `HKLM(mounted)\System\MountedDevices`, and modify the data by hand. I've done this before; see [this link](http://diddy.boot-land.net/firadisk/files/mounteddevices.htm) for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will consider active partition to be C:. If you somehow install windows on partition which isn't active, active will still be C:. I think it can also be done by installing windows and changing active partition later.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this accidentally.  In my case the system had one hard drive with two partitions, one for the system the other for data.  I needed to reload the system because the system's file system was corrupted.  To ensure the system partition was OK, during the reinstall I told the installed to delete the system partition and recreate a fresh partition and install Windows on it.  After the install, I found the installer called the data partition C: and loaded Windows on the newly created partition D:.  I eventually needed to delete all partitions to get Windows to make the system partition C:.

I never tried to recreate this on demand.  Also, I don't remember if I rebooted after the deletion and then restarted the install process to create the system partition.  After reloading Windows so many times to fix the system drive on C, they kind of all blurred together.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: [How can I change the System partition drive letter in Windows XP?](http://www.petri.co.il/change_system_drive_letter_in_windows_xp.htm), if you are trying to moved the whole folder/drive.

If you trying to moved specific folders, such as the Program Files, then you will need edit the [Windows Environment Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) via the registry.